# Printing Julia Expressions in a Readable Format

Tags: printing, julia, expression

I am working with Julia and using the **`Expr`** type to represent expressions programmatically. When I print the expressions, I get output like the following for an example program:

```
$(Expr(:toplevel, :(v1 = 1), :(v2 = 2), :(v3 = v3 + v2 + v1), :(v4 = v3), :(module m1
  v3 = v3 + v4
  v6 = 6
  v6 = v3 + v5 + v6
  function f1()
      v7 = v7 + v5 + v3
  end
  end)))
```

However, I would like the output to be more human-readable, like:

```
v1 = 1
v2 = 2
v3 = v3 + v2 + v1
v4 = v3

module m1
v3 = v3 + v4
v6 = 6
v6 = v3 + v5 + v6

function f1()
  v7 = v7 + v5 + v3
end

end
```

Is there a way to customize the printing of Julia expressions to achieve this? I want the output to be formatted in a way that is easier to read and understand. Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can “trick” Julia into displaying this expression by changing `:toplevel` to `:block` (the `head` of the expression `quote ... end`):

```
julia> e = Expr(:toplevel, :(v1 = 1), :(v2 = 2), :(v3 = v3 + v2 + v1), :(v4 = v3), :(module m1
         v3 = v3 + v4
         v6 = 6
         v6 = v3 + v5 + v6
         function f1()
             v7 = v7 + v5 + v3
         end
         end));

julia> e.head = :block
:block

julia> e
quote
    v1 = 1
    v2 = 2
    v3 = v3 + v2 + v1
    v4 = v3
    module m1
    #= REPL[53]:1 =#
    #= REPL[53]:2 =#
    v3 = v3 + v4
    #= REPL[53]:3 =#
    v6 = 6
    #= REPL[53]:4 =#
    v6 = v3 + v5 + v6
    #= REPL[53]:5 =#
    function f1()
        #= REPL[53]:5 =#
        #= REPL[53]:6 =#
        v7 = v7 + v5 + v3
    end
    end
end
```

This obviously changes the original expression, so you probably want to change it back (`e.head = :toplevel`) before using it again.